# Error output stream is concurrent with standard output stream when printing in Java

Tags: java, printing, concurrency

When this code gets executed, it produces scrambled outputs with no particular order between `System.out.print()` and `System.err.print()`. Why is that so?

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    System.out.print(i+" ");
    System.err.print(i+"+");
}
```

Why is the standard error output stream is concurrent with standard output stream when printing in Java?

Comment: Because they're two different streams, but in a console application they flush to the same output buffer: the console. This is why you should use proper logger library instead of always writing to the same stream.

Comment: ok, that makes things clear, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`System.out` and `System.err` are two different streams and so, they work at different times. The problem you're experiencing here is because in console applications both streams are flushed to the same output buffer, which is the console. Each stream can flush at different time, the console buffer will care about the synchronization for you, but this leads to unpredictable results.

If you want/need to have a single and better managed output for both streams, use a logger library like log4j2 or logback, that already solves these problems.

Comment: so we have to streams (**sources**) that write on the same file, so how the console buffer cares about synchronization?

Comment: @muslimguy the console will decide which stream will flush first and second, but this is unpredictable since they come from two different threads. While a logger synchronize the output of both `System.out` and `System.err` in a single stream.